# Error "No value was passed to the mandatory parameter" in constructor of subclass

Tags: constructor, abstract-class, abap

This is my abstract superclass:

```
class ZMP_ACAR definition
  PUBLIC
  ABSTRACT
  create public .

public section.
  DATA: maxSeats TYPE i,
        maxKidSeats TYPE i,
        carKidSeats TYPE TABLE OF REF TO z280819_kidseat,
        carPeople TYPE TABLE OF REF TO z280819_person.
  METHODS CONSTRUCTOR
    IMPORTING maxSeats TYPE i
              maxKidSeats TYPE i.
  METHODS goToTrip ABSTRACT.
protected section.
private section.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ZMP_ACAR IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD CONSTRUCTOR.
    me->maxSeats = maxSeats.
    me->maxKidSeats = maxKidSeats.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

This is my subclass inheriting from an abstract superclass above

```
class Z30082019_BMWCAR definition
  public
  inheriting from ZMP_ACAR
  final
  create public .

public section.
  METHODS CONSTRUCTOR
    IMPORTING maxSeats TYPE i
              maxKidSeats TYPE i.
  METHODS addKidSeatToCar REDEFINITION.
  METHODS goToTrip REDEFINITION.
protected section.
private section.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS Z30082019_BMWCAR IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD CONSTRUCTOR.
    super->constructor( ).  "--> ERROR: No value was passed to the mandatory parameter "MAXSEATS".

    me->maxSeats = maxSeats.
    me->maxKidSeats = maxKidSeats.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD goToTrip.
    ... 
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

It throws an ERROR inside Z30082019_BMWCAR's constructor implemenatation - line see above:
`ERROR: No value was passed to the mandatory parameter "MAXSEATS"`.

Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: The error message seems quite descriptive to me. Why do you manually set the instance variables (`maxSeats` and `maxKidSeats`) in the derived class `Z30082019_BMWCAR` instead of passing them as arguments to the constructor of the base class `ZMP_ACAR`? The error message comes up, because these parameters are not marked as optional. Also from a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) point of view this is reasonable.

Comment: @konstantin so should I have in `Z30082019_BMWCAR` something like this `super->constructor( me->maxSeats, me->maxKidSeats  )`?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot pass `me->maxSeats` but only `maxSeats` since the instance variable is not assigned yet (the assignment happens in the base class constructor). And the actual ABAP syntax is quite bloated as soon as you're passing more than one parameter.

Comment: There's a documentation embedded (F1) or [online](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenmethod_calls_static.htm) to help you.

Comment: 1) The error says that you didn't pass the parameter, so it's obvious that you should try to pass the parameter, no need to ask the question the way you did. If you had tried, maybe you had a better question why passing the same parameters is needed, is there an alternative? (if you know a language which allows it then mention it). 2) Instead of asking again for having a second confirmation, I think you could try first the proposal, then revert back if you need some clarification.

Comment: @konstantin maybe you can add an answer by replicating your comments + add the valid syntax for `super->constructor( ... )` + link to documentation (that's just a proposal). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also U can completely remove constructor from `ZMP_ACAR` and put it inside `Z30082019_BMWCAR`. Not so elegant but it would work.

```
class ZMP_ACAR definition
  PUBLIC
  ABSTRACT
  create public .

public section.
  DATA: maxSeats TYPE i,
        maxKidSeats TYPE i,
        carKidSeats TYPE TABLE OF REF TO z280819_kidseat,
        carPeople TYPE TABLE OF REF TO z280819_person.
  METHODS goToTrip ABSTRACT.
protected section.
private section.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ZMP_ACAR IMPLEMENTATION.

ENDCLASS.
```

```
class Z30082019_BMWCAR definition
  public
  inheriting from ZMP_ACAR
  final
  create public .

public section.
  METHODS CONSTRUCTOR
    IMPORTING maxSeats TYPE i
              maxKidSeats TYPE i.
  METHODS addKidSeatToCar REDEFINITION.
  METHODS goToTrip REDEFINITION.
protected section.
private section.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS Z30082019_BMWCAR IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD CONSTRUCTOR.
    super->constructor( ).
    me->maxSeats = maxSeats.
    me->maxKidSeats = maxKidSeats.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD goToTrip.
    ... 
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: > "U can completely remove constructor from ZMP_ACAR and put it inside Z30082019_BMWCAR"


By doing so OP probably violates prior code design decisions/existing principals. Who knows if other components do compile if the constructor is removed from the base class? Since ABAP does no real dependency or consistency checks during the build but only "activates" single classes or modules you should think twice before removing the constructor or at least create a where-used list of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the signature of the base class (`ZMP_ACAR`) constructor, it has two mandatory (non optional) importing parameters. Provide them when instantiating the derived class (`Z30082019_BMWCAR`). The ABAP syntax is a bit bloated when passing more than one argument to a function but this should work:

```
CLASS Z30082019_BMWCAR IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD CONSTRUCTOR.
    super->constructor( EXPORTING maxSeats = maxSeats
                                  maxKidSeats = maxKidSeats ). 
    ""// me->maxSeats and me->maxKidSeats are now inherited (public) instance variables from the super class.
  ENDMETHOD.
```